# Grammars that require unlimited lookahead?

Tags: parsing

I've been reading on different kinds of parsers, and in several papers people have mentioned grammars requiring unlimited lookahead, but an example is never given. Is there some canonical example I should be aware about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to come up with unambiguous grammars which require unbounded lookahead. Consider the following simple one:

- S → SX
- S → SY
- SX → X B x
- SY → Y B y
- X → a
- Y → a
- B → b
- B → B B

Here we cannot decide whether to reduce an initial `a` to `X` or `Y` until we've read all the way to the end of the input. But that's not too interesting because the language itself is obviously parseable with an LR(1) grammar.

There are also languages for which no LR(k) grammar exists. I think the canonical example is the language of all even-length palindromic sequences (with an alphabet of size at least two) which has the unambiguous grammar:

- P2 → a P2 a
- P2 → b P2 b
- P2 → ε

It should be intuitively clear, at least, why this requires unbounded lookahead: we cannot know when to do any reduction until we're exactly halfway through the input, but we cannot know the length of the input until we've seen all the input.